# Exception using EntityManager and Glassfish v3 - IllegalStateException: Attempting to execute an operation on a closed EntityManager

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, glassfish-3, entitymanager

I work in a project that uses JavaEE. I work with Glassfish servers version 3. I'm frequently having a problem (not always) in my singleton EJB's that use an EntityManager instance. A lot of times, I get this error:

```
[timestamp] [http-thread-pool-8080(49)] ERROR com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler.serializeResponse Attempting to execute an operation on a closed EntityManager.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to execute an operation on a closed EntityManager.
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.verifyOpen(EntityManagerImpl.java:1662) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jar:2.3.4.v20130626-0ab9c4c]
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:643) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jar:2.3.4.v20130626-0ab9c4c]
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:532) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jar:2.3.4.v20130626-0ab9c4c]
 at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.find(EntityManagerWrapper.java:320) ~[container-common.jar:3.1.2.1]
```

The log goes on, but I just showed the top of it. The next line of the log was the call to an WebService deployed in the same server. And **when** this error happens, it is always originated by a call to a WebService deployed in the **same server** that performs a find in the database using the method 'find' from the entityManager instance.

The entity manager is being injected outside of the bean in the @PostConstruct of a @WebService annotated class, using the line '(EntityManager)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/persistence/etc");' This is the class that receives all the incoming requests and decides which bean should be called, based on request.

Right after receiving a request, this class calls the respective singleton bean, based on the request, passing the injected EntityManager to the respective bean.

I understand that the EntityManager is closed when I try to perform the operation and that is indeed the problem. However, I thought this opening and closing of the EntityManager was managed automatically. Apparently it doesn't work that way. I'm not closing the EntityManager directly anywhere in the code either.

I'm not seeing any reasonable solution to approach this problem. All I find in online resources is that it **may** be a Glassfish bug and restart the server **generally** works. Nothing concrete to solve the problem.

Some of the information present in the PersistenceUnit configured in the persistence.xml file I'm using is presented below.

```
<persistence-unit> name="XXX" transaction-type="JTA"
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider></provider>
<jta-data-source>jdbc/YYY</jta-data-source>
<properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Oracle"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.size.default" value="0"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.type.default" value="None"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving.internal" value="false"/>
            <property name="toplink.target-database" value="Oracle"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.session.customizer"                       
            value="aaa.bbb.ccc.IsolateEmbeddablesCustomizer"/>
 </properties>
 <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
 </persistence-unit>
```

Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem and did any of you also got the same error?

Thank you.

Comment: You have put a lot of effort on explaining the situation which is a good thing. But you might have saved some effort and a down-vote if you had put your code instead. I recommend you to put the relevant pieces of code (not the whole classes) to explain your situation better.

Comment: I understand. I will try to update as soon as possible. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I think the the problem lies just here:

> The entity manager is being injected outside of the bean in the
>   @PostConstruct of a @WebService annotated class, using the line
>   '(EntityManager)new
>   InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/persistence/etc");'  ...

Container provides `EntityManager`s from some pool it maintains. EMs have some lifecycle and they can become invalid at some point of time. Normally (explained a bit later) this would not be a problem since usually EMs are injected in a managed way.

But you initialize it once in `@PostConstruct` to some variable and when EM pointed by that variable gets invalid it is not re-initialized or so because it is no managed by container the way meant to be.

I think you can get around if this problem by just checking if EM is invalid and doing the lookup again if reference is not valid. **But** I stress: that is not the correct way.

> passing the injected
>   EntityManager to the respective bean.

Do not pass the EM. Initialize EM in the bean that uses it. You will not have any *savings* by passing the one and only instance. On the contrary it can make the performance worse. Let the container handle the optimization of creating of EMs.

So , **normally** you would be doing something like this in your beans (not passing the EM but managing it on a bean):

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="XXX") // "unitName" might not be needed
private EntityManeger em;           // if you use only one persistence unit
```

to make EM managed correctly. That way container makes sure it is always valid.

If you have correctly constructed beans that you let container to initialize by for example `@Inject`ing those to your `@WebService` this should be possible.

If for some reason it is not possible then you might still do a JNDI lookup in the bean but then I am quite sceptic about functionality of any JTA transactions or so.

Comment: What do you mean by checking if the reference of the EM is valid? Just checking if the EM is open with the method isOpen()? And if it is not open, call the JNDI line again "'(EntityManager)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/persistence/etc");'" to reinstantiate it? I want to do a change that has the least impact possible in the project. I'm thinking about changing the @WebService annotated class to check and update (if needed) the EM reference always before calling the correspondent bean. I think passing this EM reference to be injected inside every bean is a big change in the project.

Comment: Testing like doing some operation inside `try{}catch{}` -block. But I strongly discourage this. Instead you might want to try to replace the lookup in `@WebService` with `@PersistenceContext` instead of injecting in every bean. And if this is not possible you just have to decide: do big changes or live with bigger problems. Anyway I am not saying that there are no other possibilities but this is how I would fix it.

Comment: Will not the JNDI in this case in the @ WebService class retrieve exactly the same closed entityManager instance? I'm using the @ PersistenceContext annotation at the beggining of the @ WebService class with the unit name defined in the persistence.xml file. I'm not using the @ PersistenceContext tag directly in the EntityManager attribute of this class, since the EntityManager as I already said is being retrieved by the JNDI. I guess by now you already understood the EM setup of this project that I have to deal with. Yes I'm evaluating to see which is the best solution for this problem.

Comment: @Amorfi I doubt but maybe it does. test it. When you do a JNDI lookup you do not lookup any specific instance but a resource that has been defined in that path. `<jta-data-source>dbc/YYY ...` is configured somewhere in your Glassfish server and as a container it decides what to return. And I am pretty sure there is some pool of something.